# How can I compare model performance across datasets of varying sizes?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, paired-data

I have a person wearing 2 sensors. I create two models, one using Sensor-1 and other using Sensor-2 data

[image]

I have multiple people repeating the same experiment with varying numbers. How do I a statistical comparison between the two sensors based on data availability and model performance?

Comment: I've heard of this in other settings, for instance, evaluating of Lyft driver A, who has nine 10-star reviews and one 9-star review, is better than driver B, who has a thousand 10-star reviews and a thousand 9-star reviews. Sure, driver A has the higher average rating, but...

Comment: Please provide more details. Many things are unclear  e.g. what do you mean by 'based on data availability'?